# How to replace the input data by matrix containing training data

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I have deep neural network where it does the training as below way :

```
# Training and testing phases
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Training
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(1001):
        avg_cost = 0.
        for index_m in range(20):
            input_samples = []
            input_labels = []
            for index_k in range(0, 1000):
                bits = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.5, size=(10,))
                input_data = input_funct(bits, SNR)
                input_labels.append(input_data)
                input_samples.append(input)

            batch_x = np.asarray(input_samples)
            batch_y = np.asarray(input_labels)

            _, cs = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                           Y: batch_y,
                                                           learning_rate: l_rate})
```

My question is about this generated data `input_data = input_funct(bits, SNR)` , : how many times it will be generated? as I see it will be generated following the three `for loops` as : 1001*20*1000 = 20000000 times,  right?  assuming the the size of columns = 10; 
Now, If I have the data as a matrix of same size already generated and imported as file of size `(20000000,10)`, I need to put it in place of `input_data`  and take them column by column to process the training.  how can I do that? of course the command of `bits = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.5, size=(10,))` will be imported in similar way instead of generated it here randomly.

Normally I suppose to add new `for loop` for all columns, but I don't know where and how since I'm newbie in python programming.

thank you

EDIT:

What' about this way, where I added another loop of total size and then added the other loops of inside it.

```
# Training and testing phases
#label is the imported matrix of size(10 x 20000000)
#data is the imported matrix of size(10 x 20000000)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Training
sess.run(init)
for j in range(1001*20*1000)
    for epoch in range(1001):
        avg_cost = 0.
        for index_m in range(20):
            input_samples = []
            input_labels = []
            for index_k in range(0, 1000):
                bits = label(:,j)
                input_data = data(:,j)
                input_labels.append(input_data)
                input_samples.append(input)

            batch_x = np.asarray(input_samples)
            batch_y = np.asarray(input_labels)

            _, cs = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                           Y: batch_y,
                                                           learning_rate: l_rate})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TWENTY_MILLION_TIMES_TEN_ARRAY = open('hi.txt','r').read()
np.reshape(TWENTY_MILLION_TIMES_TEN_ARRAY,(1001,20,1000))
# Training and testing phases
j = 0 # example
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Training
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in list(TWENTY_MILLION_TIMES_TEN_ARRAY):
        avg_cost = 0.
        for index_m in list(epoch):
            input_samples = []
            input_labels = []
            for index_k in list(index_m):
                '''whatever you do with that data and label'''
                # input[j] blah blah....
                j += 1

            batch_x = np.asarray(input_samples)
            batch_y = np.asarray(input_labels)

            _, cs = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                           Y: batch_y,
                                                           learning_rate: l_rate})
```

this is what I would do, reshape the array and just pass it down.

you could also generate the data in the format in the first place so you don't even have to reshape it.

hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you so much for your reply.  I got it, but what's about the way I suggest in my modified question? Is that right too?  .. since I'm still a beginner in python, so I prefer the easy ways :)

Comment: @New_student that would not work! you are doing 1001*20*1000 twenty million times! you don't need that loop you added. I can see that you want the index `j`, you could just declare a variable before the loop begins `j=0` and add one to it every time.

Comment: @New_student I would still suggest you generate the data in the `1001,20,1000` structure in the first place. You could use something like `np.empty(1001,20,1000)`. This way you could pass the entire `1000` array into the NN without having to make a list every time.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got what you mean, and it's ok.  but could you please clarify how to add j=0 and then add one to it every time ?  could you please add it into the answer you gave? .. thanks again.